# Evaluating power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

> How do I evaluate the power series
> $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n}{9^{n}}$$
> without using the formula for infinite geometric series?

I am interested in an approach which doesn't make use of infinite geometric series.

Any help would be highly appreciated. New approaches are most welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: But, even if you want you can not apply infinite geometric formula because $q$ is not a constant.

Comment: Just for curiosity - why is a geometric series forbidden? For me this sounds like a question on elementary number theory forbidding the use of prime numbers.

Comment: I'm looking for some new approaches to evaluate the series.

Comment: I think all approaches will more or less involve calculating infinite geometric series.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps to evaluate my series, it would be very nice if you could elaborate by answering to the question. I highly appreciate your time and efforts. Thanks.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the exact value, but you can compare it to the integral, which converges since $|\frac{1}{9}|<1$, $\int_{0}^{\infty}x a^x dx$, which will be of the same order, and then derive the difference using Bernoulli polynomials.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how? I highly appreciate your time and efforts. Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: I think my solution is incorrect tbh; for some reason, although it should be the case, the integrand is not $xa^x$

Comment: I mean they must be of the same order by Euler-Maclaurin formula, but they are not for some reason: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula

Comment: I see, Any other approach?

Answer (score 2):

Check with induction that the partial sum is
$$\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{k}{9^k} = \frac{9 - 9^{-N}(8N+9)}{64}$$
Evaluate the limit when $N$ goes to infinity and you get the result.

Comment: This approach rather seems to be very naive

Comment: Just to be honest, as @DavidMitra pointed out in the reference, there is a known formula for partial sums of series like this, and this result is derived using "geometric series results". However you could pretend to be blind and use induction on a formula that comes from heaven and you are done lol.

Comment: lmao Thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $x \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}ix^i $. So differenciating you get $$x \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$ Substituting $x= \frac{1}{9}$ you get required answer.

Comment: How is this not using the geometric series? Don't you need to know in advance that $\frac 1{1-x}=\sum_{i\geq 0} x^i$?

Comment: Yeah this does uses geometric series :(

Comment: Well you can compute derivatives in zero...however not complete, but in general I do not see why one should restrain from using a basic identity such as the geometric series to use more involved methods (you also need to prove that your convergence radius of the Taylor expansion is greater than $1/9$ which involves study of analytic functions...)

Answer (score 0):

Denote $A=\sum_{n\geq 1} n9^{-n}$, $B=\sum_{n\geq 2} n9^{-n}$, $C=\sum_{n\geq 1} 9^{-n}$, $D=\sum_{n\geq 2} 9^{-n}$. You have the closed system
$$
A=B+\frac 19,\quad 9B-A=C,\quad C=D+\frac 19,\quad 9D=C,
$$
which gives the value of $A$. Of course, as a byproduct of the computation one also gets the value of the geometric series $C$.

Comment: Seems like all approaches are using geometric series

Comment: well at least here we are not using the result, but deriving it.